# Fill container with non-repeating map with Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found a couple of people asking this question on here but the answers all had a map that didn't fill 100% of the screen so if you zoomed out it wouldn't repeat but you'd get gray bars above/below the map.

If you go to maps.google.com, no matter how far you zoom out, no matter how wide or tall your window, the map *always* fills the screens and *never* repeats. I can't figure out how to do this with the Google Maps JS API and I can't find anything on StackOverflow of this exact behavior.

For a visual, this is the default behavior (afaik) from Google Map's API:

[image]

Here is maps.google.com at the same screen size and zoomed out as far as they let you

[image]

If you make the window even wider Google Maps' site seems to resize the map to constantly stay 100% wide/tall so no gaps and repeats ever happen. How do I do this?

Comment: They seem to prevent users zoom out more. Check the map on the second picture, India is invisible, so, not a full view of the map is visible (both horizontal and vertical sides).

Comment: Right, it can't always fit it perfectly because of arbitrary window dimensions, but it fits it as nice as it can. It's like CSS' cover property. If it can it fits it within the window but if not it bleeds a bit out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may calculate the minZoom based on the size of the map.

The minZoom would be:

```
mapWidth<=256:0
mapWidth<=512:1
mapWidth<=1024:2
mapWidth<=2048:3
```

The formula:

```
Math.ceil(Math.log(map.getDiv().offsetWidth/256)/Math.log(2))
```

possible implementation(including re-centering the map)

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'resize',function(){

  if(map.get('bounds_listener')){
    google.maps.event.removeListener(map.get('bounds_listener'));
  }
  else{
    map.set('_center',map.getCenter());
  }

  map.setOptions({
    minZoom: Math.ceil(Math.log(map.getDiv().offsetWidth/256)/Math.log(2))
  });

  map.setCenter(map.get('_center'));

  map.set('bounds_listener', google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(){
     this.set('_center',this.getCenter());
  }));
});

//trigger resize to set initial value
google.maps.event.trigger(window,'resize');
```